# node.js electron bootstrap-tour popover is not a function

Tags: jquery, node.js, electron

Hy,

I make a node.js application and i have a problem with bootstrap-tour.

I have two files `index.js` and `tour.js`.

In `index.js` i have something like this :

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
require('./tour.js');
```

and in `tour.js` something like this :

```
const Tour = require('bootstrap-tour');
var tour = new Tour({
        steps: [
            {
                element: "#account",
                title: 'Your account',
                content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'
            }]
    });
tour.init();
tour.start();
```

But i have this error in electron's console :

> Uncaught TypeError: $element.popover is not a function
>       at Tour._showPopover

I tried to add `require('bootstrap');` just before `const Tour = require('bootstrap-tour');` but the same error still appear.

Someone can help me ?

PS: 
Is that a good way to do it? Or is it better to put all the javascript in `<script>` tags and put all the code in `document.ready` functions ?

PPS: 
Here my `package.json` content :

```
{
  "name": "testelectron",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "TestElectron",
  "main": "app.js",
  "author": {
    "name": "OOM"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.6.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-toggle": "^2.2.2",
    "bootstrap-tour": "^0.11.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found a solution?

Comment: @dayd
No, I use another library instead :/ 
I use : [Shepherd](http://github.hubspot.com/shepherd/docs/welcome/), but it's not a very good solution because it's hard to fight with it (like opacity of background like the exemple, z-index special case etc...) Contact me if you need some help to use it. (sorry for my english)

Comment: Thanks, I also used the shepherd for a while, but in the end I created my own solution ...  (sorry for my english too :p)